# Login page is not redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a login page for the web using HTML and javascript with firestore as the DB.

The problem is whenever I complete the login form, the page just refreshes. The console does not return any errors. (note that upon executing the page, the console does not return any errors as well.)

**"loginPage.html"**

```
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="limiter">
            <div class="container-login100">
                <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-30 p-b-20">
                    <form id="loginForm" method="POST">
                        <img src="images/icons/diabeatis.jpg" width="70%" style="margin: 0px auto 20px;display: block;" alt="AVATAR">
                        <span class="login100-form-title p-b-40">
                        <font face="Montserrat">By Team Buendia</font>
                        </span>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-t-25 m-b-35" data-validate="Enter username">
                            <font face="Montserrat">Email</font>
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="loginEmail" style="font-family:Montserrat;" id="loginEmail" required>
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-50" data-validate="Enter password" >
                            <font face="Montserrat">Password</font>
                            <input class="input100" type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" required>
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" style="background-color:orange; font-family:Montserrat; cursor:pointer; font-weight:bold" id="btnLogin">Login</button>

                        <ul class="login-more p-t-40">
                            <li class="m-b-8">
                                <a href="signup.html" class="txt2" style="color:#01703D">
                                    <font face="Montserrat">Create Account</font>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="signin.js">
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(user){
                window.location.href = "patientDashboard.html";
            }
        });
        </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
</html>
```

**signin.js**

```
(function(){
    //initialize the firebase app
    var config = {
               *assume there are credentials here*
        }; 

        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var auth = null;
        var loginBtn= document.getElementById('btnLogin');

    //Login
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#loginEmail').val() != '' && $('#loginPassword').val() != '' ){
        //login the user
        var data = {
            email: $('#loginEmail').val(),
            password: $('#loginPassword').val()
        };

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
            .then(function(authData) {
            auth = authData;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then it should be redirected to this page named **patientDashboard.html**
Assume that all js imports are already present. I already added this code to the aforementioned html file

```
        <script src="signin.js">
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(){
            if(user){
                window.location.href = "loginPage.html";
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: update: I think I already tried all the coding style/format for the js file. Nothing seems to work, this is so weird. Because when I use the same coding style for the  ```firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()```  it works like a charm.

Comment: You have `window.location.href = "loginPage.html";` - is that correct? Wouldn't that just refresh loginPage.html?

Comment: @DougStevenson based on the tutorials I've been following that is the code to execute a proper redirection from one page to another (ex. login page -> firebase.auth() -> dashboard) I'm still trying to understand what it means unfortunately. Ref Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQGTfuYFD6k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple problems in your code, first:
1. the script signin.js is currently not executed since you wrap it in a function but not called

```js
(function () {
    ...do something here then don't forget to call the function by `()`
})();  // <--- this will execute whatever code within the function scope
```

2. your script that handled redirect is located at the wrong block
   your

```js
<script src="signin.js">
   // any code here will only execute whenever the `signin.js` failed to load for any reason
</script>
```

so for your redirect to work you need to store it in another script block or maybe   put it somewhere you like

I tried to recreate your code with the fixes mentioned above the the redirect works fine.

`sidenote`: if you are working on vanillaJS then be consistent, you are also using jQuery, `$`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks mate! Though I already noticed point number 2 earlier that you made and I made necessary adjustments. I just forgot to update my code here.